# search using jqgrid

Tags: php, jquery, sql, jqgrid

I want to implement a search function with jqGrid, that will search by column.  What is the easiest way I can implement this using code sample bellow?

Right now, all I can get this to do is to display from the database, and sort asc or desc.

Grid :

```
<script>
   jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({ 
   url:'server.php', 
   datatype: "json",
   colNames:['A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
   colModel:[ 
           {name:'id',index:'id', align:"center"}, 
           {name:'testcolumn1',index:'testcolumn1', align:"center"}, 
           {name:'testcolumn2',index:'testcolumn2', align:"center"},
           {name:'testcolumn3',index:'testcolumn3', align:"center"},
           {name:'testcolumn4',index:'testcolumn4', align:"center"},       
   ],
   rowNum:10, 
   rowList:[10,20,30], 
   pager: '#pager2', 
   sortname: 'id', 
   recordpos: 'left', 
   viewrecords: true, 
   sortorder: "asc", 
   height: '100%'
   });
```

Form :

```
<form class="form-inline" id="searchForm">
    <input id="testcolumn1" type="text" class="form-control searchTxt" placeholder="testcolumn1">
    <input id="testcolumn2" type="text" class="form-control searchTxt" placeholder="testcolumn2">
    <input id="testcolumn3" type="text" class="form-control searchTxt" placeholder="testcolumn3">
    <input id="testcolumn4" type="text" class="form-control searchTxt" placeholder="testcolumn4">
    <button id="search" class="form-control searchTxt"> Search </button>
</form>
```

Comment: There is an example in the jqGrid Demo's page that implements search on columns. I would start there.   http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html -> Searching -> Toolbar with operations.

Comment: @scrappedcola In the demo, the columns have the search options pre filled out, such as "sopt:['eq','ne','le','lt','gt','ge']".  I want to enable the user to use the form to search across each column

Comment: So do you want to search per column or across columns? The search options are selectable based on how you want to filter. Do you want a direct match, starts with, not equal to etc. These you will use no matter what type of filter you apply as a filter without a type is meaningless.

Comment: @scrappedcola I want to search across pickable columns, but if not possible, at least one column. So for example, if a column contains 3 records (apples,bananas,oranges) I want to be able to type "ban" and then search to come up with bananas

Comment: @scrappedcola So you are saying "sopt" is the type of search?  if so, what do the abbreviations mean, and also, how do I get it to run in php/html?

Comment: yes sopt is the search type. if you click on the == in the demo a drop down shows you the various types. "eq" ==, ne !=, le <=, ge >=, lt <, gt >. There are more and if you click the icon next to each column in the demo you can probably figure them out. The filter, if I'm not mistaken, is done on the clientside by the grid. Though if you read through the docs there is probably a way to offload to the server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85350/discussion-between-steven-and-scrappedcola).

Comment: Improved wording and format of the code.